# Why is the quotient map from the sphere to the real projective plane open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, open-map

By *'open map'* I mean that the quotient map $q\colon S^2 \to \mathbb{RP^2}$ maps open sets in $S^2$ to open sets in the projective plane $\mathbb{RP^2}$.

My thinking is the following:

> $q\colon S^2 \to \mathbb{RP^2}$ is an open map $\iff \forall$ open $U \subseteq S^2,\ q(U) \subseteq \mathbb{RP^2}$ is open $\iff \forall$ open $U \subseteq S^2,\ q^{-1}(q(U)) \subseteq S^2$ is open. Now, $q^{-1}(q(U)) = U$ so we must have that $q$ is an open map because $U$ is open in $S^2$.

Is this correct? Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: Nope. In general $q^{-1}(q(U)) \ne U$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost. We have $q^{-1}(q(U))=U\cup(-U)$. And that is open as union of open sets.

Comment: Cheers Hagen, is $q^{-1}(q(U))=U \cup (-U)$ because the projective plane identifies antipodal points of $S^2$?

Comment: @Joseph Exactly. To show that the quotient map is open one needs to use specific properties of the map somewhere :)

Comment: Of course, thanks a lot :)